# Random MOSFET failure in MPPT Buck converter circuit

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, failure

I'm making a buck converter with a microcontroller driven PWM signal to drive six N-channel - well heatsinked - MOSFETS to perform MPPT into a lead acid battery from a solar panel. The system works well for hours with no problem but I'm facing a regular issue in that out of a parallel of 6 MOSFETs, one (randomly out of  six) MOSFET fails after a day of running. Only one MOSFET fails (GDS shorted) and the panel voltage is pulled down to battery voltage. There is no physical damage to the MOSFET. It looks good, but the leads show short. The 4R7 gate series resistor, 47K gate-source resistor, and 2x15V back to back gate-source Zeners are all fine, but not the MOSFET.
The system has also been made to shut off the gate drive when the solar voltage drops below the battery voltage, which takes place at sunset.

The same issue - one random MOSFET failing - also takes place for any number of MOSFETs used - 1 to 6.

I tried adding a relay at the solar input to the MOSFETs to disconnect the panel after sunset, but no change.
Last evening, the system charged the battery till it was full, then stopped charging with the solar voltage at 38-42VDC (near Voc, thus showing no switching taking place). At 6:15Pm, the panel voltage dropped to less than the battery(12v) and after the solar relay disconnected, the solar voltage dropped to 2-3 VDC by 6:45PM. The system remained on with the full battery till I checked in at about 7AM. It was showing solar voltage near battery voltage, so the failure may have

1. already taken place before relay connection,
2. taken place when the solar relay connected, or
3. taken place just after that.

My solar panel develops 42Vp at 330Wp, and my MOSFETS are IRF540N which have a 100v VDS rating.
I'm hunting for possible causes and solution(s), on and off for quite some time now because of viral lockdowns etc. The circuit is a standard buck converter with a relay before the IRF540N switch, and a 6mH inductance after the switch. Pulse width starts from near zero when charging starts, up to almost full width when needed, varying as the system follows MPPT to get maximum power into the large battery.

Here is the schematic, at last :
[image]

This is the drive circuit:
[image]

Your valuable ideas and suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: You should add a schematic. In fact, without a schematic this question is not really a question.

Comment: Schematic and oscillograms needed.

Comment: And layout, too.

Comment: You have to realize that a synchronous buck converter is a bi-directional converter in essence. If the low-side MOSFET keeps switching while the battery is connected - which is surely the case - then you create a boost converter with your sync rect being the main switch and the \$V_{DS}\$ voltage keeps increasing until you stop switching or, most likely, the weakest of the paralleled devices (either the low- or high-side) gives up. I actually gave an answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535163/buck-converter-problem/535180#535180

Comment: The gate drive circuit looks weird, it should include a connection to the top MOSFET source to drive it

Comment: Thanks for that heads up, but this is not a synchronous converter. The lower MOSFETS are used as diodes, Though it was the original idea I had started with, but decided to make this work first, then think about synchronous switching. The schematic shows the gate and source pins are shorted.

Comment: The isolated gate drive circuit - what powers it and how?

Comment: The driver is a toroid Gate Drive Transformer with primary driven by a complementary push pull with the signal from a micro .

Comment: Links please and/or circuit. You are aware that if the relay is on AND the panel voltage drops slightly below battery voltage, the bulk diode inside the 6x MOSFETs will conduct and back-power your panels.

Comment: Yes  The panel has a diode in series. I'll add the drive circuit now

Comment: Actually, the panel has string fuses/diodes to prevent back power taking place.
The system firmware also looks at the panel voltage constantly, and if it goes below the battery, it shuts the relay off after stopping charging.

Comment: What are the 100nF/Rk7 supposed to do in the gate drive circuit?

Comment: Are the MOSFETs on the same heatsink or very tightly thermally bonded? They share best when they are thermally connected.

Comment: Yes, the MOSFETS are on the same heatsink.
The circuit forms a snubber in case of transients

Comment: I'm talking about the components labeled "DCRM" they look like they would eat most of the gate drive current

Comment: Yes, bobflux, that's the RCD snubber to prevent spikes from damaging the switch. My switch works at 50KHz, so the R needs to be relatively small to discharge the C before next switch. The gate signal is consistent at 12+V.

Comment: The system works in the day. Its during the night or just when the relay switches On - it's after the solar voltage crosses battery voltage by 1 volt that I switch ON the relay to start charging - that I am facing issues. I'm not sure exactly when yet. I need to simulate the situation and check, looks like